# Starting to think that Maven is overkill for my current project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am working on a Spring Web Project that we are using Subversion, Eclipse and JBoss to build it.

The way we have it now is that we check everything into Subversion, the source code, jars that the project needs (Spring, Log4J, etc), so at any time someone can go to Subversion and rebuild the project.

Most of the projects at this firm only have one programmer on each project and the firm only has 3 programmers anyway.  We are thinking about using Maven, but I am starting to think that it is overkill...  Can I please get some feed back about your views on this?

Comment: Maven is pretty lightweight, helps to enforce consistency across projects and developers, and frees you from handling dependencies as binaries (and from checking in them in svn).

Comment: Of all the descriptions of Maven I've seen, “lightweight” isn't the first to come to mind. (Of course, nothing that does all that Maven does could really be lightweight in the first place…)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a system that works for you, then don't change it.

On the other hand Maven helps a lot in keeping up with dependencies changes.
In most cases with Maven you have to update a dependency version in one place and a new version of that dependency is there ready to be tested and used.

If you decided to switch to Maven, you must have some kind of local repository management system like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).  Think of it like a source control for your binary dependencies.  Another must would be Maven support in your choice of IDE.  I think at this point all major Java IDEs have it.

At one point I was exactly in the same predicament and decided that it was worth it to switch (and it was).

However, mastering the whole setup may be daunting.  If nobody at your company did it before, I think it may take somebody on your team 4-6 weeks to do a conversion project (learing Maven concepts, setting up POMs, integrating with IDE, etc.).  Hence weigh carefully future benefits against current deadlines.

Comment: Also note that it is much easier to *start* a project with maven than to *convert* to maven later.  However, I would recommend against using it for a high value project before getting you feet wet with a personal/low priority one.

Comment: An other point: it is much more easy to start with maven with an easy, small project. -- So I think you should do maven with you projects.